# How to add Exchange calendar to Sunrise calendar app

Tags: exchange

I'm trying to add an Exchange account to the Sunrise calendar app, but I get the error: `There is no Exchange accounts available on your device.`

Where should I add this Exchange account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Open **Settings** (for your phone, not the Sunrise app)
2. Scroll down to **Accounts**

[image: Settings]

3. Tap **Add Account**

[image: select "Exchange"]

4. Select **Exchange Account**
5. Set up your **Exchange Account**

[image: follow the instructions]

Comment: Thanks! On my Samsung Galaxy S6 this is called `Microsoft Exchange ActiveSync`, but for the rest your steps match :)